# Un-used function & variable in tsconfig.json or tslint setting (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

Folks, anybody knows how to detect un-used method & un-used Variable from component or service code is there any setting in tsconfig.json file or tslint settings

i have already used two setting in tsconfig.json file for un-necessary exports and un-used parameter

"noUnusedLocals": true,
"noUnusedParameters": true,

Answer (score 1):

Checkout these ESLint rules:

- [eslint-plugin-unused-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-unused-imports)
- [no-unused-vars](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars)

You need, of course, to have [ESLint setup](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started) in place, but that's outside of the question scope